# How do I get a list of labels and values for a GCE instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

How do a get a list of labels & values that have been applied to an instance from within the instance itself?(I am writing a script that will invoke this from within the instance, so even if it means using API, it would be welcome.)

The documentation gives commands like:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="labels.environment:*"
```

That query returns something like

```
    NAME   ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE    PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
node1      us-central1-a  n1-standard-2   true         10.135.224.51               RUNNING
node2      us-central1-a  n1-standard-16               10.135.224.52               RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the details of a GCP instance using this API:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get

Included in the details is the set of labels associated with the instance.

You can get your own GCP instance resourceId by querying the metadata within your own instance:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

Comment: The API looks like the best way. Cheers.